# Some issues with the storing of rss feeds in the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, rss

Untill now I have more or less succeeded with parsing rss feeds (xml-based documents) from different websites into my MySQL database by following code (rss storer.php):

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

$feeds = array(
    'http://fotbollskanalen.se/rss',
    'http://www.aftonbladet.se/sportbladet/fotboll/rss.xml',
    'http://www.eurosport.se/fotboll/allsvenskan/rss.xml',
    'http://expressen.se/rss/fotboll'
);

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("You could not access!");
mysql_select_db("storage",$connect);

if($connect)
{
foreach( $feeds as $feed ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

    foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
    {
    $date_format = "j-n-Y"; // 7-7-2008
    echo date($date_format,strtotime($item->pubDate));  
             echo ' <a href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->title.'</a>';
             echo '<div>' . $item->description . '</div>';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO rss_feeds (id, title, description, link, pubdate) 
    VALUES (
        '', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->title)."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->description=htmlspecialchars(trim($item->description)))."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->link)."', 
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($item->pubdate)."')");       
    }
}
}
else
{echo "An error has occured";}

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

As a result it shows the rss feeds from the 4 links when I am driving this script as test and also I have seen that it respons to the database on my server because there has been files inserted into the mysql table.

But now it's here the problems are comming. These below are the problems I need to get help with:

1: When I am looking into the mysql table "rss_feeds" on the database, I see a lot of strange letters that seemed to have replaced the Swedish letters "Å", "Ä" and "Ö" and I assume that it could be something with the charset on the rows in the mysql table resp. the database itself. But if it is so, then how do I change it to solve this problem?

2: Although the MySQL database "storage" responses on the PHP codes in "rss storer.php", I have not seen new RSS feeds get inserted since the database and the PHP file got connected with each other. Should I add another PHP code in "rss storer.php" or what shall I do so the absolute latest RSS feeds get inserted into the database?

3: When it comes to the ID on the RSS feeds on the database, they all show 0. How do I make them unique, it will say that every RSS feed has different ID?

4: When I am looking at the publishing date of the RSS feed in my table "rss_feeds" on database "storage", they all show "0000-00-00 00:00:00". Why is it so? Following code is fore the pubdate row in the database:

```
5       pubdate timestamp   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   Null: No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

5: This is the last one issue, but could be the most important. I want to set a limit in the mysql table "rss_feeds" on database "storage" about the maximum of inserted rss feeds so the rss feeds do not grove up too much and somehow threat the whole local server if you understand what I mean. Shall I add some SQL code to decide the limit or how should it be done?

If you need some more additional necessary information in order to help me with these issues, then I'll provide more information to you as wished.

I will wish all the best greetings to those, who will help me through all these issues :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) Check the encoding of the DATABASE CONNECTION. I don't think it is UTF-8.

Comment: When I drive the PHP script on a testing server, then it shows the right letters and not the strange ones. But the biggest problem is when the RSS feeds get stored. When I then again check in the mysql table placed on the database "storage", then the strange weird letters appear instead of the real Swedish letter (Å, Ä, Ö).

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

$feed->set_output_encoding('ISO-8859-1');

This will ensure the output from the RSS feed matches the MySQL encoding. Otherwise you end up with characters like  â€.
Source: http://samueljcarlson.blogspot.in/2011/12/rss-feeds-to-mysql-database-script.html